# Setting a radix in c

Tags: c, hex, set, radix

I need to implement an arithmetic algorithm for hexadecimal numbers. So I want every arithmetic operation i.e addition, multiplication, subtraction, and division to be performed in base 16.

Is there anyway to sort of set a base?

Comment: Why? Just convert input to normal base 10 and do your arithmetic normally, and convert to hex when printing results. Also, no compiler that I know of allows changing the internal radix.

Comment: works out of the box: `int x = 0x20 + 0x10;`

Comment: @Joachim, I am trying to multiply two 100 bit hex numbers. I am getting the input in hex..so i asked. Converting a number that astronomical in size to decimal is not smart i think.

Comment: Do you mean 100 _bits_ or 100 _digits_? Either way, you might want to look into something like the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/). Using something like that it's easy to convert input in any base to very large decimal numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please.

Modern computers work in binary, by directly operating on voltages that represent 1s and 0s. That's just they way they work, you can't change that in software.

What you can do is change the base used for I/O, so that you print out numbers in hexadecimal, for instance:

```
int a = 47, b = 95;
int c = a + b;  /* Look, we add two integers! */

printf("%x + %x = %x\n", a, b, c);  /* Print terms and sum in HEX. */
```

This will print:

```
2f + 5f = 8e
```

Note that the variables are initialized from decimal numbers, but we can still *print* the values in hex.

Comment: Thanks a ton @unwind. I got a start now, I think I can fix the input thing now. Thanks! :D